# Error trying to connect to MongoHQ database from node.js app

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Can't seems to understand what is the problem.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

console.log('Trying to connect with', settings );

MongoClient.connect( settings.mongourl, settings.options, function(err, db) {
    if(!err) {
        console.log("We are connected");
        callback( true, db );
    }
    else {
        console.log("Connection failed", err );
        callback( false, null );
    }
});
```

In result I get (changed some parts to xxxx):

```
Trying to connect with { mongourl: 'mongodb://xxxx:xxxx@xxxx.mongohq.com:xxxx/testdb', options: {auto_reconnect: true}}
Connection failed [Error: failed to connect to [xxxx.mongohq.com:xxxx]]
```

I have doublechecked the url string for connection, everything is ok, tried to create another user just for testing - still getting errors. The worst part is that the description in error doesn't give any hint what cause the problem.

Just in case, my package.json dependancy part:

```
"dependencies": {
"fetch": "~0.3.6",
"mongodb": "~1.4.3",
"connect-mongo": "~0.4.1",
"amqp": "~0.2.0",
"express": "~4.1.1",
"express-session": "~1.0.4",
"connect": "~2.15.0"
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use the same connection string and try to connect using mongo client.

```
mongo --host "xxxx.mongohq.com" --port "XXXX" --username "" -p ""
```

See if you can connect thru the shell or not.

For more info look here: http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/mongo/#bin.mongo

Comment: Nope, I can not. It gives the following output: Error: couldn't connect to server xxxx.mongohq.com:xxxx at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:147
exception: connect failed

Comment: Yeah, so if you cannot connect with mongo shell then you will definitely will not be able to connect from NodeJS. It's better you check with the admin if the mongod server is up or if you need any proxy or VPN access to connect.

Comment: Hmm, so it seems something might be wrong on mongohq site. Have submitted them issue, we'll see what will they answer.